# iPhone : Problem with iAdBannerView - not able to see in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have implemented iAdBannerView. Its giving me the following warning :
"ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x136d20) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view."  what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to get those warnings constantly when I placed my iAds too close to the edge of my screen, but they're not that big of a deal. Did you implement all of the delegate methods for iAd? (I believe there's only 1 or 2 that have to be implemented, and if they're not you'lll get a warning). And are you seeing "Test Advertisement" in the iAd? If so, you should be fine... remember, you get paid per click, not per view, so as long as the users can see it you're good.

Also, just as a side note: iAd has horrible fill rates (it's sometimes as low as 5% for me), so you might want to look into using something like admob concurrently with iAd. Adwhirl is great for just this: it can display iAd if there is an ad available, and admob otherwise. That way you maximize your revenue.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i'hv implemeted 1 delegate method. In simulator it showing me "test advertisement" but in device it is displaying nothing !

Comment: Yup that's perfectly normal, iAd isn't exactly the best at showing up 100% of the time. As long as that's the only error you're getting you should be fine. Take a look into AdWhirl too, if you're planning on making money from ads it's well worth the time put in!

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code, this may help you out:

```
[adBannerView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```